# How to Convert xml columns into html values in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have loaded some values in #Temp table like below,

```
Select 12 as ReporterID,'<tr><td>Saravanan</td></tr>' As Body into #Temp
Insert into #Temp values(12,'<tr><td>Yogaraj</td></tr>')
Insert into #Temp values(22,'<tr><td>Daniel</td></tr>')
Insert into #Temp values(22,'<tr><td>Mathan</td></tr>')
```

I want the output like,

```
 Reporter              Body 
   12        '<tr><td>Saravanan</td></tr>tr><td>Yogaraj</td></tr>'
   22        '<tr><td>Daniel</td></tr>tr><td>Mathan</td></tr>'
```

I have tried below code it convert it into xml. but i want it in html.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tttm.ReporterID
       , STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + t.Body
            FROM #Temp T
            WHERE T.ReporterID = tttm.ReporterID
            FOR XML PATH('table')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS tags_title
--into #XML
from #Temp tttm
```

someone please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sql server v17.9.1

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This probably isn't the best solution, but I believe it accomplishes what you want.*

What you can do is have a nested query: The outer query groups by `ReporterID`, and the inner query gives you the XML you need. This is similar to your attempt. But with my solution, I'm stripping out the `td` text, and then putting it back into the requisite elements in the `FOR XML` part of the query:

```
SELECT
    ReporterID,
    (
        SELECT Body.query('//td/text()') AS td
        FROM @tmp AS t2
        WHERE t2.ReporterID = t1.ReporterID
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ROOT('table')
    ) AS combined_body
FROM @tmp AS t1
GROUP BY ReporterID
;
```

working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75f2baa11e29e908dac2b51714f7aa45).